# Operation composition in tensorflow-1.14,15

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to make a very simple operation in tensorflow 1.15.
I have a pretrained network that I want to use for inference.

This network exposes a `tf.global_variable` let's say `input` and an output say `output`.
Now having a session variable `sess`, if you want to do inference, you just run:

```
inference_output = sess.run(output, {input: input_numpy})
```

My problem is that I have already implemented a frontend to this inference (to calculate `input`) which is a set of tensorflow operations that I will call `exp` and which expects an input variable say `args`.

I **can't** find a way so the value of `exp` is feeded to the global variable `input` and thus my graph becomes:

```
args -> (expr -> input) -> output
```

Right now I am doing this as:

```
preprocessing_inp = sess.run(expr, {args: args_numpy})
inference_output = sess.run(output, {input: preprocessing_inp})
```

but what I would like to have only one operation (so everything does a single gpu pass):

```
inference_output = sess.run(output, {args: args_numpy})
```